# Problem connection with lotus notes database with maven project

Tags: java, maven, lotus

I want to retrieve data from a lotus database notes in my java code with odbc connection in my maven project .. I have done several searches for that without a good result, is it possible to make ? If you have any ideas can you help me with? Thank you

Comment: The [JDBC-ODBC](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/bridge.html) bridge was removed in Java 8. What version are you using?

Comment: Version of odbc? Version 7

Comment: Version of **Java**.

Comment: Oh i don't no excatly but not java 8